# 'debugger' command and JSLint

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jslint

Google Chrome supports [debugger command](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#debugger) as a tool to setup a breakpoint in code. How can I hide warnings for the following code in [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/):

```
/*globals $, console, */
/*jslint browser:true, white: true */

function test() {

        "use strict";
        debugger;     // JSLint reports the "Unexpected 'debugger'" error
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JSLint has an [explicit option](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options) to tolerate `debugger` statements, called `debug`:

> `debug`: `true` if `debugger` statements should be allowed.

You can specify this option via your `jslint` directive:

```
/*jslint browser:true, white: true, debug: true */
```

Comment: **+1** Preferred Answer, as you'd have to implement `ignore jslint` in multiple locations otherwise

Answer (score 4):

This error is raised to highlight a lack of convention and possible oversight by the developer.

You can disable it via:

```
function test() {
    /* ignore jslint start */
    debugger;
    /* ignore jslint end */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears `debug` is gone, and [this is now tolerated with the `devel` option](http://jslint.com/help.html#devel), with the side effect that `// TODO:` etc are also tolerated with the single `devel` option.

> `devel`: `true` if browser globals that are useful in development should be
>   predefined, and if `debugger` statements and `TODO` comments should be
>   allowed. It adds the same globals as this directive:
>
> ```
> /*global
>     alert, confirm, console, prompt
> */
> ```
>
> Be sure to turn this option off before going into production.

This lints:

```
/*jslint white, devel */

function test() {
        "use strict";
        debugger;     // JSLint reports the "Unexpected 'debugger'" error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in react I used to do it during development like this:

```
debugger // eslint-disable-line
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable `no-debugger` to make it work! (only applicable in Typescript **tslint**)

```
"rules": {
    "no-debugger": false
 }
```