# Is bad practice keeping the "debugger" instructions on javascript on production environment

Tags: javascript, production-environment

I am performing some fixes and improvements on an existing website before it goes into a production environment and I have seen a few javascript functions with the `debugger` statement in them, is it bad practice to keep them in the productive environment ?

Comment: I don't see any value in having them there as you don't really try to debug PROD.

Comment: Yes. You will break the interwebs :P

Comment: Yes, why would you leave them in?

Comment: Or the interwebs will break you, as some debugger code might introduce security holes

Comment: Why would you keep it **after** debugging? JsLint and TsLint can be used to track it [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20884559/427146) I usually gets a call from the lint if I miss it.

Comment: Pros : none; Cons : it can totally break your code execution and your site. Now it's your call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the actual debugger statement, yes they need to be removed. When encountered in execution they may cause the scripts to stop executing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: Isn't that only while dev tools is open, though?

Comment: I believe it is variable based on environment. I haven't used it much myself, but IIRC I heard it will actually open the developer tools for chrome?

Comment: We've been developing against Chrome (internal app) for the last year, and I have yet to  observe that behavior. But point taken that it could be environment specific.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The debugger must be used exclusively when developing and *debugging*. There is literally no possible gain from leaving those statements in production.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) are the docs in case you want to give them a look.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to linting/hinting tools debuggers should be removed as soon as you are done with them. 
Also, **most of the time** debugger/console statements are removed when you prepare your code for production deployment (uglify/minify).

See this:
http://jslint.fantasy.codes/all-debugger-statements-should-be-removed